# If referer = "/search", do X, else do Y: "bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

I have a problem with Ruby and URI. I want to test my referer:

- if referer contains "/search", display X
- else display Y

**Controller:**

```
@referer = URI(request.referer).path
```

**View:**

```
<% if (@referer == '/search') %>
    <p><%= link_to('<< Back to results', :back)%></p>
<% else %>
    <p>Tadamm</p>
<% end %>
```

**Problem:**
When there's a referer, like "search", it's ok. When there's no referer, like direct access, I have this error:

> bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@referer = URI(request.referer).path
```

The `URI` method expects a "URI object or URI string." But if there's no referer, then you're not giving it either of those. This is equivalent to calling `URI(nil).path`. A quick fix would be:

```
@referer = request.referer && URI(request.referer).path
```

This way, if there's no referer, `@referer` will be set to `nil`, and your `if` statement will work as expected.

Comment: Thx Jordan, it's OK now !
And i understood ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
@referer = request.referer ? URI(request.referer).path : nil
```

Comment: Thx Sergey for your quick answer